# Loading and unloading content from library in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm doing a flash project but I'm new to actionscript. 
I have a menu in the main page and I want to make other pages appear when I click on menu items.

I know how to load movieclips from library but I don't know how to specify their position on the screen and how to make them appear in a specific layer.

Is it necessary to unload previous content when I click on another item of menu?
will they stack on each other and make the program heavy if I don't unload them?!

I've added a layer for each menu item and added the following code in each of them (For every item there is a different class):

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

btn_msg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowMessegePage);

function ShowMessegePage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var msg_page:MessegePage = new MessegePage();
    addChild(msg_page);

msg_page.x = 495;
msg_page.y = 323;

}
```

I have placed an image in the first frame as the main page. Then I placed some buttons each on separate layers. In order to load a page while clicking on each button, I have added the above code.

When I click on button A, Page A is loaded, when I click on button B, page B is loaded and so on. How can I see the main page again? I have added a button for the main page but for some reason I do not what to load it from library, it is in the first frame and under loaded contents. My question is how can I remove loaded contents so that I can see the main page again? Should I remove every previously loaded content when I click on every button and then load new contents?

Comment: Please post some code to demonstrate your current attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Loading MovieClip from library:**

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MyClipID();
parentLayer.addChild(mc); // parentLayer can be any DisplayObjectContainer, even the stage
```

**Positioning a loaded clip:**

```
mc.x = 15;
mc.y = 30;
```

**Removing a loaded clip:**

```
if(mc.parent)
{
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
}
```

**Placing a clip at a specific "layer" (index):**

```
parentLayer.addChildAt(mc, 0); // this will place it behind everything on parentLayer
```

***UPDATE:*** To answer your latest question, yes, you *should* remove the previously loaded clip before adding a new one. Then, when you want to display the main image again, you can just remove the currently loaded clip.

***UPDATE2:*** An example of keeping track which page is currently loaded and removing it before displaying a new page:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var currentPage:DisplayObject;

btn_msg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowMessagePage);
btn_msg2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowMesssagePage2);

function ShowMessagePage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeCurrentPage(); // remove the old page
    var msg_page:MessagePage = new MessagePage();
        addChild(msg_page);

    msg_page.x = 495;
    msg_page.y = 323;
    currentPage = msg_page; // keep track of the current page
}

function ShowMessagePage2(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    removeCurrentPage(); // remove the old page
    var msg_page2:MessagePage2 = new MessagePage2();
        addChild(msg_page2);

    msg_page2.x = 495;
    msg_page2.y = 323;
    currentPage = msg_page2; // keep track of the current page
}

function removeCurrentPage():void
{
    if(currentPage && currenPage.parent)
    {
        currentPage.parent.removeChild(currentPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this way of positioning safe? I mean does it change on different screen resolutions? How can I return to the first page? My first page is an image placed in the first frame.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your other follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks. About my other question, if I position my loaded clip using x and y, does its position change on different screens with different resolution? (I guess it doesn't, right?) Is there a better way for positioning? this one is a little hard to determine!

Comment: I suggest you find a tutorial on Fluid/Liquid layouts in AS3 (just one example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-fluid-website-layout-with-flash--active-1108).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still having a problem with removing loaded contents. I don't know how to check if anything is loaded then remove it!

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Perhaps, the simplest method would be to keep track of each item as it's loaded. If you're loading multiple items, you can store their references in an `Array`. Then you can remove them using the method above.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: The answer has been updated. I highly recommend refactoring the code for readability/reusability. There's really no need for each button to have its own event listener. You could easily have one event listener that reads information from the button (probably its name) to determine which item to load from the library.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that! And I know that is another question and needs another place!