# AS3 delay removing displayObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have made a menu by loading some pages from library (more detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940461/loading-and-unloading-content-from-library-in-as3))

Each page has an animation inside it. It's like a door opening and closing, almost like [this](http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_265_theme).
I have used this code to remove the old page and add the new page:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var currentPage:DisplayObject;

 btn_msg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowMessagePage);

function ShowMessagePage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  removeCurrentPage(); // remove the old page
  var msg_page:MessagePage = new MessagePage();
     addChild(msg_page); // load new page

     msg_page.x = 495;
     msg_page.y = 323;
     currentPage = msg_page; // keep track of the current page
}
```

The problem is that It removes the old page before the door is closed.
Is it possible to delay the removal of the old page?
This is my first serious experience with flash, so I don't know much about actionscript.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my try to use a timer, in order to delay the removal of the old page:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


var currentPage:DisplayObject;
var msg_page:MessegePage = new MessegePage();
var gallery_index:GalleryPage = new GalleryPage();
var film_index:FilmGallery = new FilmGallery();

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(9000,1);

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, removeCurrentPage);

btn_msg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowMessegePage);
btn_img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowGalleryPage);
btn_film..addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ShowFilmPage);

function ShowMessegePage(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
addChild(msg_page);
msg_page.x = 495;
msg_page.y = 323;
msg_page.gotoAndPlay("msg");
currentPage = msg_page;
myTimer.start();
}

function ShowGalleryPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
addChild(gallery_index);
gallery_index.x = 495;
gallery_index.y = 323;
gallery_index.gotoAndPlay("indexofgallery");
currentPage = gallery_index;
myTimer.start();
}

function ShowFilmPage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
addChild(film_index);
film_index.x = 495;
film_index.y = 323;
film_index.gotoAndPlay("film");
currentPage = film_index;
myTimer.start();    
 }

 function removeCurrentPage(event:TimerEvent):void
{

if(currentPage && currentPage.parent)
{
    currentPage.parent.removeChild(currentPage);
}
StopTimer();
}

function StopTimer():void
{
myTimer.stop();
}
```

But it removes the new page that is loading!
I think I should keep the old page somehow ...

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried using an array with 2 cells.
When I click on each button a DisplayObject will be added to the array and a function is called to check if the other cell of the array contains an object or not. 
If it contains an object, it will be removed.

I tried to write the code for my idea, but it doesn't add and remove Objects to the array correctly!

Comment: Is door animation part of Page that will be added, or just removed?

Comment: @NicolasSiver: it's part of the page.

Comment: I can't find in your code logic where you trigger animation of closing.

Comment: @NicolasSiver: The animation is inside each page and each page is a movieClip ... I have set a label to the beginning of each animation in each page ... Take a look at my "Show..."  functions.

Comment: I understand `show` behaviour, but where is your closing behaviour? So you don't want to remove instantly previous page.

Comment: @NicolasSiver: Sorry, what do you mean by "closing behaviour" ?

Comment: @NicolasSiver: The closing and opening door are both in the beginning of every page ...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest of all: [`setTimeout()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29). Not perfect but it will fix your issue at the moment. Best way is to know if the new animation is finished, but it goes in some kind of complex solutions for you. This is easiest, but don't overuse it, as it has it's weaknesses.

Comment: In the link you refereed to says "consider creating a Timer object". How can I do that?

Comment: Come on man, start using Google! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: I do use google! But I'm running out of time. I was hopping for a quick answer when I asked my question here! by the way, I added "var intervalId:uint = setTimeout(removeCurrentPage, 100);" but it didn't work.

Comment: 100 means 100ms. Don't know if your animation is that long.
And about the timer - this site is for dealing with problems, not doing your entire job. The reference has examples in it with a few lines of code, that actually work!

Comment: "100 means 100ms. Don't know if your animation is that long." It doesn't delay at all!

Comment: Should I use "intervalId" somewhere?

Comment: My project uses AIR 3.6. Is it because of that? The reference says "Runtime Versions:AIR 1.0". Is it supported in later versions ?

Comment: If you don't call removeCurrentPage directly, and simply use setTimeout, it WILL work, but you need to provide proper time. Try using bigger value, not 100, as this is a tenth of a second, which you can't feel.

Comment: I tried using timer. I used this: "var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, removeCurrentPage);
myTimer.start();" but it has errors. "Argument count mismatch on project_fla::MainTimeline/removeCurrentPage(). Expected 0, got 1.
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick()"

Comment: Check out the reference!!! removeCurrentPage must take one argument..
Sorry, but this is getting really annoying, you simply want someone to write your code, which is truly sad.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to annoy you. Actionscript is so new and vague to me! And I'm not patient with errors!

Answer (score 0):

If each page has a `MovieClip` on it, then you should be able to remove the old page just after you've added the new page:

```
function ShowMessagePage(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     var msg_page:MessagePage = new MessagePage();
     addChild(msg_page); // load new page

     removeCurrentPage(); // remove the old page

     msg_page.x = 495;
     msg_page.y = 323;
     currentPage = msg_page; // keep track of the current page
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your comments. "It doesn't work" doesn't help me to help you.

Comment: Nothing changes. The old page is removed the moment I click the button. By the way, I've included a gotoandplay command to a label in each page (which is a movieclip itself). If I don't add this, the door animation which is inside it doesn't work.